# Change mat-slider color dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

In a Angular Material v17 application, the slider should change color based on some external state:

```
<mat-slider [color]='sliderPalette()'>
  <input matSliderThumb #s>
</mat-slider>
```

where

```
/*
 * The theme defines three primary, accent, and warn color palettes.
 */
public sliderPalette() {
  return state ? 'accent' : 'warn';
}
```

This works fine.

But instead of using the active theme's palettes, I want to define two different color palettes and use those instead:

```
/*
 * Color palettes not related to the theme.
 */
public sliderPalette() {
  return state ? 'color-palette-state-0' : 'color-palette-state-1';
}
```

defined in my `theme.scss` theme definition file:

```
$color-palette-state-0: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-palette);
$color-palette-state-1: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);
```

or just redefining Angular Material's predefined blue and red palettes:

```
$color-palette-state-0: mat.$blue-palette;
$color-palette-state-1: mat.$red-palette;
```

but neither of these work -- the sliders just turn a static purple with no error message.

The [Angular Material Slider API](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api) docs hint that this is not possible:

```
@Input()
color: ThemePalette     Palette color of the slider.
```

so the `color` is a `ThemePalette` so perhaps the palettes **have** to be part of the theme.

Interestingly, the [Angular Material Button API](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api) is different:

```
@Input()
color: string | null    Theme color palette of the button
```

so, perhaps, this is bug/design problem with the slider.

Any ideas how to do dynamically change the color of the `mat-slider` preferably without overriding internal styles? But, really, at this point, I'd take any solution.

Comment: Can you please share the code for 'blue-palette' and 'red-palette'?

Comment: I believe the `mat.$blue-palette` and `mat.$red-palette` are Angular Material predefined palettes...though the docs are all focused on themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll take a look at the definition of the `ThemePalette` [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/5799c142c54ccb0e3023ea7572b6f4b0762f487b/src/material/core/common-behaviors/color.ts#L33), you'll see that it's actually one of the pre-set palettes on a material theme. There's no way to apply custom palettes here.

It's roughly based on the material design [color system specs v2](https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-and-palettes), so the "internals" of Angular Material don't really have ways of handling other palettes defined within a theme.

If you want to use the built-in theming tools, what you CAN do is switch between two defined themes and / or predefined theme palettes. This is the approach that I would recommend.

You will have to define more than one theme, and apply one only under certain circumstances, e.g. if the container contains some class:

```
// Define a dark theme
$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
 color: (
   primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette),
   accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette),
 ),
  // Only include `typography` and `density` in the default dark theme.
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  density: 0,
));

// Define a light theme
$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette),
   accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette),
 ),
));

// Apply the dark theme by default
@include mat.core-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);

.use-light-theme {
  @include mat.core-color($light-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
}
```

Then you can apply one of the two themes dynamically by adding / removing the class from the element:

```
<mat-slider [ngClass]="{'use-light-theme': useOtherTheme}">
  <input matSliderThumb />
</mat-slider>
```

Alternatively, you can import your palettes into your component's stylesheet, extract their values manually and apply them to different .css variables that apply colors to the slider:

```
.use-some-color {
  --mdc-slider-handle-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($color-palette-state-0, default)};
  --mdc-slider-active-track-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($color-palette-state-0, default)};
  --mdc-slider-inactive-track-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($color-palette-state-0, default)};
}

.use-other-color {
  --mdc-slider-handle-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($color-palette-state-1, default)};
  --mdc-slider-active-track-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($color-palette-state-1, default)};
  --mdc-slider-inactive-track-color: #{mat.get-color-from-palette($color-palette-state-1, default)};
}
```

And then switch between the classes:

```
<mat-slider [ngClass]="{'use-some-color': !useOtherColor, 'use-other-color': useOtherColor}">
  <input matSliderThumb />
</mat-slider>
```

Of course for that to work, you have to know exactly which hue from the palette to apply to which variable, so you might have to take a look at the source code of `mat-slider`. Also, this might be more prone to errors after version changes than the first solution.

Here's a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/znaili-joosjq). Note that it's quick and dirty (i.e. importing whole theme.scss into component, ouch!), but should give you the right idea.